# SQLite Query with TWO columns referring to ONE

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am stumped. I am trying to write a SQLite query where I have two tables.  One table has two columns that both point to the same column in the second table.  For example,

```
Table1
ID     Text     Sender     Recipient    
1     Hi There  1          2 
2     What?     2          1
3     Weirdo!   3          1

Table2
ID    Name     Screenname
1     Me       Me
2     Sally    Sal_gal
3     Bob      Bob
```

I am trying to write the query where I would get the following results since both the Sender and Recipient from Table1 point to the ID in Table2.

```
Results
ID       Text       Sender       Recipient
1       Hi There    Me           Sally
2       What?       Sally        Me
3       Weirdo      Bob          Me
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `JOIN` twice:

```
SELECT t1.ID, t1.Text, t2.Name AS Sender, t3.Name AS Recipient
FROM Table1 t1
JOIN Table2 t2
  ON t1.Sender = t2.ID
JOIN Table2 t3
  ON t1.Recipient = t3.ID;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/405479)**</kbd>

Output:

```
╔════╦══════════╦════════╦═══════════╗
║ ID ║   Text   ║ Sender ║ Recipient ║
╠════╬══════════╬════════╬═══════════╣
║  1 ║ Hi There ║ Me     ║ Sally     ║
║  2 ║ What?    ║ Sally  ║ Me        ║
║  3 ║ Weirdo!  ║ Bob    ║ Me        ║
╚════╩══════════╩════════╩═══════════╝
```

I've asssumed that you have defined foreign between both tables. Otherwise you may need to use `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: Thank you !  Worked perfectly !